# Android: setResult not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Scenario: I have a `MainActivity.java`, `OtherPageForFragments.java` and a fragment which is on `OtherPageForFragments.java`

In `MainActivity.java`, I have written the following code to start an activity and get result in

> onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

is

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, OtherPageForFragments.class),REQUEST_CODE_MAP);
```

In the `onDestroy()` of the fragment class, i have written this:

```
public void onDestroyView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroyView();
        mlocManager.removeUpdates(this);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("Latitude", passLatLng.latitude);
        intent.putExtra("Longitude", passLatLng.longitude);
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        getActivity().finish();
    }
```

Now, I want my result in the `MainActivity` class. So, i have written the following code in the `onActivityResult` method:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_MAP)
        {
            tost("2");
            double lat=data.getExtras().getDouble("Latitude");
            double lng=data.getExtras().getDouble("Longitude");
            tost(lat + " -- " + lng);
        }
```

The Problem: the `resultCode` getting returned is not `Activity.RESULT_OK` and the `Intent` I am getting is `null`.

What to do? Thanks

Comment: what code you are getting on ActivityRessult

Comment: You nee to pass the values from fragment to activity?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. check `Communicating with the Activity`.

Comment: why do you start a fragment with startActivityForResult?

Comment: @YogeshTatwal I want to pass intent too.  'setResult(RESULT_OK);' will  only send the resultCode

Comment: @Raghunandan from fragment to mainactivity

Comment: @micro.pravi does `MainActivity` host the `Fragment`?. If so follow the docs @http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @Raghunandan I have already cleared it above that `MainActivity` is not hosting the `Fragment` It is hosted by 'OtherPageForFragments.java'. Please read the question.

Comment: @micro.pravi which activity hosts the fragment then?

Comment: `OtherPageForFragments.java` hosts the fragment. It is another activity. read my comment and question before please @Raghunandan

Comment: @micro.pravi just a suggestion communicate the value to activity that hosts the fragment and then pass the result back to the first activity using intent. works but not sure if its the best way.

Comment: I have already done the same by creating an interface and it worked. Still thanks. @Raghunandan

Comment: @micro.pravi you are welcome. I think that's the way i can't think of a better idea at the moment.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem - I could not retrieve either the `resultCode` or the `requestCode` in `onActivityResult()`.  What did work, however, was that I was able to retrieve the data inside the Intent object.  In `setResult`, I create an `Intent` with something like: `Intent data = new Intent(); data.putExtra("EXTRA_ITEM_SAVED", true); setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);`  And in onActivityResult, I do something like: `if (data.getBooleanExtra("EXTRA_TASK_SAVED", false)) { //do something }` This is the only thing that would work for me.

Answer (score 15):

```
getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
getActivity().finish();
```

this code shouldn't be in onDestroy. onDestroy happens after the activity is already finished, and onActivityResult was called.

this code needs to in the code that closes the activity/fragment,
like on back key pressed, or a close button onClick

Comment: It is not 'onDestroy'. It is 'onDestroyView' of fragment and it is called before activity gets finished.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("Latitude", passLatLng.latitude);
intent.putExtra("Longitude", passLatLng.longitude);
if (getParent() == null) {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
} else {
    getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
}
getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: This will create a new instance on `MainActivity` on the task stack,this will not get back to the original caller of the current activity.

Answer (score 4):

maybe you need clarify the launch modes for both activities. normally they should be "standard", if there is "singleTop" ... attributes in your activity manifest file. you need pay more attention.

Comment: In my scenario , it has to be singleTask launch mode .
Is there any workaround that fix this issue without changing the launch mode to standard ?

Comment: what attention @MehdiJahedManesh?

Answer (score 4):

For me removing flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` for lauch intent resolved the issue

Answer (score -1):

The method finish() is called before setResult()

Try overiding onBackPressed() method like this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    setResult(RESULT_OK)
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

Comment: setResult() not works with super.onBackPressed() . You should use finish() instead of super.onBackPressed()

Answer (score -1):

tried all above.
**nothing worked.**

it was a silly mistake.
i was calling finish() in recycler adapter (on item click).
**and it was being called before setResult(CODE, intent);**

if all the above fails,
**comment the "finish();" and check whether "finish();" is being called somewhere else;**